# How are No Man Sky Expedition initial appearance/equipment randomized?

Tags: no-mans-sky

The recent No Man's Sky update introduced a new gameplay mode called Expedition.

> Introducing a whole new game mode: Expeditions. Each of these events starts from a fixed point in the universe, bringing the whole community of travellers together to embark on a shared journey.
> Each expedition is structured around a series of Milestones. Complete these unique exploration goals in any order as you earn rewards, meet up with fellow travellers, and experiment with new ways of playing No Man’s Sky.

Expeditions are assigned to separate game save slots. Apparently, Expeditions start from a fixed planet in the galaxy, and should follow a specific path, visiting specific "Rendezvous Planets"

> Special Rendezvous Planets along the Expedition route create dynamic hubs of activity. Reunite with other travelers on the same journey, group up with the community to build a settlement, or simply wave hello as you pass through.

That said, the initial info I got mentioned that each Traveler would be assigned a random starting appearance, ship, multitool and so on. After the patch dropped I briefly tried the new mode on a separate user account on a Ps4 console and my initial appearance was an anomaly type.

A bugfix patch later I have started the Expedition. To my surprise, even after restarting the mode multiple time I always got the same initial configuration - a Vy'keen Traveler with red armor and red multitool... Must be an Atlas sponsorship.

Yet if you look at this [Let's play video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcLRSbJvUSw)

[image]

you can see that in this case the player seems to start **on the same planet** but with a different appearance from the one I got.

Since starting the expedition multiple times without saving always gave me the same character, I am wondering. How are expeditions seeded? It is the initial player appearance tied to the current console user playing the game? And in that case how are appearance randomized on the PC version - Windows user or  something related to Steam maybe?

Answer (score -3):

I believe the player name is used to seed the randomization on the expedition start, but I cannot find a specific source for that information. I may have heard it mentioned while watching "You Tubers" playing through an expedition.

Here is a recent reference to similar complaints and thoughts about the seed for expedition generation. Perhaps it isn't character name, rather some other internal aspect of the player account?

https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/11a0kct/the_one_thing_i_hate_about_expeditions/

Comment: there are two problems with that theory: first, it would mean that on a console the player account name has to be used instead since there is no in-game player name. Second and more important - that would mean that unless you change your account name the same expedition should always start with the same initial character configuration.... This is clearly not the case since I got an Anomaly Traveler and a Vy'keen one while starting the same expedition. Time must be involved somehow, but it is unclear HOW. Multiple restarts in a short time range always produced the Vy'keen Traveler.

Comment: @Redacted Agreed, it was just a theory based on a vague recollection. Though, in earlier expeditions, I have started new expedition saves multiple times, across several days and always ended up with the same Gek, same multi-tool, and same starter ship.

Comment: @Redacted And I have not tried starting a new save on the most recent expedition (I play via Steam on PC, fwiw).

Comment: I see... that did not happen in my case. I started an expedition and got Anomaly, didn't save because I didn't had enough time and was just looking what the expedition was about, started next day and got Gek. Started again... same Gek with same tool.